# cannot run this program on cmd.exe

Tags: c, file, fopen

im trying to copy some texts from a file and save them in struct members, i run my program on cmd.exe and it crashed, but when i run it on codeblocks or visual studio it works,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct AMIGOS 
{ 
    char nom[' '];
    char apellido[' '];
    char nompila[' '];
    char tel[' '];
    char correo[' '];
    char dir[' '];
    char fecha[' ']; 
};

int main()
{
    struct AMIGOS reg;
    char registro[128];

    char**datos;
    char*dato;
    datos = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char**));
    int tam;
    int i=0;

    FILE* pt = fopen("arch.txt","r");
    if(pt==NULL)
    {
        printf("filenotfound\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(fgets(registro,128,pt))
        {
            dato = strtok(registro,"|");
            while(dato)
            {
                tam = strlen(dato);
                datos[i] = (char *)malloc(tam);
                memcpy(datos[i],dato,tam);
                datos[i][tam]=0;
                i++;
                datos[i]=0;
                dato = strtok(0,"|");
            }    
        }
        strcpy(reg.nom,datos[0]);
        strcpy(reg.apellido,datos[1]);
        strcpy(reg.nompila,datos[2]);
        strcpy(reg.fecha,datos[3]);
        strcpy(reg.tel,datos[4]);
        strcpy(reg.correo,datos[5]);
        strcpy(reg.dir,datos[6]);

        printf("%s\n",reg.nom);
        printf("%s\n",reg.apellido);
        printf("%s\n",reg.nompila);
        printf("%s\n",reg.fecha);
        printf("%s\n",reg.tel);
        printf("%s\n",reg.correo);
        printf("%s\n",reg.dir);
    }    
}
```

the text on the file:

kevin|clark|ns|march 15 2001|5555555|l@mail.com|123 street

does anybody know why it crash when i try to run it on cmd.exe ?

Comment: Do you mean that when you run the compiled executable it crashes, but when you run your code from within Visual Studio it works?

Comment: Why do you write `char nom[' ']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is writing beyond the end of the array:

```
tam = strlen(dato);
datos[i] = (char *)malloc(tam);
memcpy(datos[i],dato,tam);
datos[i][tam]=0;                 <---- 'tam -1' is the last element
```

You need to add an additional character to store the null terminator, or you could just use `strdup()`:

```
datos[i] = strdup(dato);
```

Comment: And so the solution is to pass `tam+1` to `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it works in Visual Studio but crashes in Cmd Line. But, there are a few issues in your code:

```
        tam = strlen(dato); 
        datos[i] = (char *)malloc(tam); //You are not allocating memory for '\0' character
        memcpy(datos[i],dato,tam);
        datos[i][tam]=0; //So this is effectively an array out of bound write
```

should be

```
        tam = strlen(dato); 
        datos[i] = (char *)malloc(tam+1); 
        memcpy(datos[i],dato,tam);
        datos[i][tam]=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of problems:

```
datos = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char**));
```

You actually mean:

```
datos = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
```

(Following the normal C idiom of:

```
var = malloc(n * sizeof *var);
```

would avoid this mistake.  In practice, the sizes are likely to be the same, but it is wrong in principle.  Also note that casting the result of `malloc` is also frowned upon in C.)

```
tam = strlen(dato);
datos[i] = (char *)malloc(tam);
memcpy(datos[i],dato,tam);
datos[i][tam]=0;
```

You're overflowing your buffer.  You allocated `tam` bytes of memory, then you copied `tam` bytes into it, but then you try to NUL-terminate it.  You need to allocate `tam + 1` bytes.

As other bits of advice:

- Your use of `strcpy` is unsafe; you can't guarantee that the tokenized input won't cause you to overflow those buffers as well.
- `fgets(registro,128,pt)` would be better as `fgets(registro, sizeof registro, pt)`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char nom[' '];
```

is very strange code, it almost certainly doesn't do what you expect it to. I would be interested in hearing the motivation for this code.

It will basically declare `nom` as an array of characters, whose length is given by the integer value of the character <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. Assuming an ASCII machine, this will be equivalent to:

```
char nom[32];
```

Comment: It _is_ strange indeed, but it doesn't explain why the program crashes.